# The component does not work correctly if there is more than 1 of it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following component in Vue:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { PropType } from "nuxt/dist/app/compat/capi";
  interface Star {
    id: string;
    value: number;
  }

  const stars: Star[] = [
    { id: "star5", value: 5 },
    { id: "star4.5", value: 4.5 },
    { id: "star4", value: 4 },
    { id: "star3.5", value: 3.5 },
    { id: "star3", value: 3 },
    { id: "star2.5", value: 2.5 },
    { id: "star2", value: 2 },
    { id: "star1.5", value: 1.5 },
    { id: "star1", value: 1 },
    { id: "star0.5", value: 0.5 },
  ];

  const props = defineProps({
    ratingValue: {
      type: Number as PropType<number>,
    },
    starColor: {
      type: String as PropType<string>,
    },
  });

  const emit = defineEmits(["ratingChange"]);
  const selectedRating = ref<number | undefined>(undefined);

  const roundedRating = computed(() => {
    if (props.ratingValue !== undefined) {
      return Math.round(props.ratingValue * 2) / 2;
    } else {
      return selectedRating.value !== undefined
        ? Math.round(selectedRating.value * 2) / 2
        : undefined;
    }
  });

  const onRatingChange = (value: number) => {
    if (props.ratingValue === undefined) {
      selectedRating.value = value;
      emit("ratingChange", selectedRating.value);
    }
  };
</script>

<template>
  <div class="center">
    <div :class="['rating', { disable: props.ratingValue !== undefined }]">
      <template v-for="star in stars" :key="star.id">
        <input
          :id="star.id"
          v-model="roundedRating"
          :disabled="props.ratingValue !== undefined"
          type="radio"
          name="'rating'"
          :value="star.value"
          @input="onRatingChange(star.value)"
        />
        <label :for="star.id" :class="star.value % 1 === 0 ? 'full full-star' : 'half'"></label>
      </template>
    </div>
    <div class="rating-number">{{ props.ratingValue }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

If it is only used once on the page, then it works correctly, but if there are more than one of it, then it breaks a little.

If you specify `ratingValue` then the number on the right is displayed, but the stars that should be painted in the two components are painted only in the last one.

```html
<StarRating ratingValue="1" />
<StarRating ratingValue="4" />
```

I tried to figure it out, I think the problem is with `selectedRating`, but my attempts to fix it were unsuccessful

[image: the problem]

Comment: Without knowing much about Vue, the syntax you use suggests you are hard coding the ID in a fashion that will create multiple elements with the same I’d when you add the components to the page. IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Quentin I tried to assign an ID to each element via props, but it didn’t help.

Comment: If you create a demo that would help, see https://play.vuejs.org/. The rating value is a `number` so the prop should be bound with`:` (i.e. `<StarRating :ratingValue="1" />)`. I don't see any other issues with the code and if the count is correct there is likely an issue with the styles logic. Having a better example would help.

Comment: Even if it's not the cause of your current problem, the duplicate `id`s will get you in trouble. Either drop them all together (wrap the `label` around the `input` instead) or make sure they are unique per document by, for example, giving each instance a unique prefix property and append that prefix to the `id`.

Comment: It's not Vue, but [this is a React rating component](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-tsx-star-rating-s9nyxk?file=/src/App.tsx:1,1) that I ported over from plain JS that renders multiple components. Maybe you can take some inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have unique name attributes, you could achieve it like this:

Script:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';

const uniqueId = ref(Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9));
```

Template:

```
<input
  :id="star.id"
  v-model="roundedRating"
  :disabled="props.ratingValue !== undefined"
  type="radio"
  :name="`rating-${uniqueId}`"
  :value="star.value"
  @input="onRatingChange(star.value)"
/>
```